# Apache httpclient timeout on customers machine (I/O Exception caught when processing request: Connection timed out

Tags: java, apache, rest, rally, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm recieving a timeout issue attempting to connect to and query Rally via Java code using Apache HttpClient 3.0

I do *not* get this issue using xmlhttprequest.

I cannot reproduce this on any machine but the one that it is failing on. Could this be a cacerts issue since the host is https? Could there be a way to check for proxies? Any logging suggestions to get more info?

Thanks!

Error message is:
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpmethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: connection timed out: connect.

They are running java jdk 1.6.

```
protected String doGet(HttpClient httpClient, GetMethod getMethod)
throws IOException
 {
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(this.host, this.port, null), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.username, this.password));
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(1000000));
getMethod.setDoAuthentication(true);
getMethod.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(1000000));
getMethod.addRequestHeader("X-RallyIntegrationName", this.integrationName);
getMethod.addRequestHeader("X-RallyIntegrationVendor", this.integrationVendor);
getMethod.addRequestHeader("X-RallyIntegrationVersion", this.integrationVersion);
//getMethod.addRequestHeader("X-RallyIntegrationOS", getOSInfo());
//getMethod.addRequestHeader("X-RallyIntegrationPlatform", getProductInfo());
getMethod.addRequestHeader("X-RallyIntegrationLibrary", "Apache Commons HTTP Client 3.0");
try
{ 
  double timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
  int result = httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
  double timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
  System.out.println("Seconds to query for Workspace: " + (timeAfter - timeBefore));
  if (result != 200) {
    throw new IOException("Http GET Failed" + getMethod.getStatusLine());
  }
  String response = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
  System.out.println(response);
  return response;
}
finally
{
  getMethod.releaseConnection();
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Rally REST Toolkit for Java: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava

This handles a ton of the code you have written above (and is built using a newer version of the Apache Http Components- 4.2.x)